синтаксический разбор
Встречались мы или нет, сейчас не имеет никакого значения.
Это БСП?

Синтаксический разбор:
Встречались мы или нет, сейчас не имеет никакого значения.
Это БСП, отношения меду частями предложения изъяснительные, обозначены запятой.
Возможна постановка тире в предложении другой структуры:
А встречались мы  или нет — значения не имеет.
Можно сравнить (СПП с изъяснительным придаточным как аналог): Не имеет никакого значения то, что встречались мы или нет.
